# facebook - remove people you may know

Tags: facebook, greasemonkey

I'm just getting into facebook now.  That "people you may know" section  that pops up is driving me to distraction, and I'm just trying to get rid of it.

I have a greasemonkey script but its not working.  None of numerous posted Greasemonkey scripts to remove it work either.

In the source for the facebook page , the "People You May know" (PYMK) section is in a script element that contains just one very long function call, i.e.

```
<script>big_pipe.onPageletArrive({"phase":1,"id":"pagelet_ego_pane","is_last":true,"css":["30YXW","MA+x5"],"js":["uBXoU","LNwoY","NavLF","ZtuLL"],"onload":["window.__UIControllerRegistry[\"c4dc09ff06275f0732488206\"] = new UIPagelet(\"c4dc09ff06275f0732488206\", 
...
```

So I'm just trying to remove that script element and I tried this as a first pass:

```
function Remove_PYMK() {


  var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');    


  for (n=0; n<scripts.length; n++) {    
    if (scripts[n].innerHTML.indexOf("People You M") >=0) { 
      scripts[n].style.visibility="hidden";
      alert ("found it");   
    }   
  } 


}


Remove_PYMK();

//document.addEventListener("onload", Remove_PYMK, true);
```

It finds it, it just doesn't remove it.

This is something of a kludge, needless to say.  Is there a proper way to disable PYMK, and ALSO, prevent my name from showing up in PYMK on other people's page.

EDIT:

Here's the entire script node up until the string "People You May Know" (FWIW):

```
<script>
    big_pipe.onPageletArrive({
        "phase": 1,
        "id": "pagelet_ego_pane",
        "is_last": true,
        "css": ["30YXW", "MA+x5"],
        "js": ["uBXoU", "LNwoY", "NavLF", "ZtuLL"],
        "onload": ["window.__UIControllerRegistry[\"c4dc09ff06275f0732488206\"] = new UIPagelet(\"c4dc09ff06275f0732488206\", \"\\\/pagelet\\\/generic.php\\\/WebEgoPane\\\/\", {}, {});; ;", "new EmuController(\"6002939839588-id_4dc09ff0611f60c83869379\", \"AQBsgeDBRnJ4uiUuieZs681Fm3aqB5-626iHBbItdNfF5TWZZJ-9dZ60xyVaJr7JfimJpKgKNxXqF_DH_aHjru3RItUcHs2gI_ZLQNYdIENRSM5zh_pcjiDZyN7vv0trj5UDBOfXp6A6yDdVCZDLntgw1fU3cFSjPQkk9KQHnU3B61bkLQfoyQzysiefB82Ptf7tgkHDqlDwNpUT-HhYPOr8yGKxD6XavtgIfsW9hLPfGy6Eg7POsGHDyXrIDrl-Q3HM2CPoByeL43H0wIklCdbe8Oi3VnfKa-ysGjLB8YuAZHOJ1GH9feOxFphmcHE5C1R15rcPdnXSOaBI5bIJdJ24pIfAlNmGjXSMHU5LOiBm3FvCi_WzotJKxeRPjMBRmqQXw2CJ-xhFGGFqGRfJvoa9m8XKb1YpXzx-pqcpzDJ1z2xz3TT7gvObi5U-9ZaRtzNHY5g0UI3W-JeYjC-67Ir74mltDpXojdx-fWG5c-3OoX5bNJrCh1ifbQKFn3wLDAMdUHk4h8GO5eJdP_1xvJFal0SWZnwnMbty2AAd7EeFcSQNkjdK9BViqFo7OLLh8tT-j9k1fNnccza4M9jN94NEEjXRxU2KYhSGjdKL0fMJCfYA1y-3MMi7WbwEg7QiH-0AY_vQCu75j7vBtrwhjVpIK4kpBpNLYx5ucqLMe1RXt3PkE-xY0Jr5LRtwDq6MjeLrCjP0JaBL9o55o2DGPN-MNndM5YSCiZbri6ms7kJ0DADuZxiWkZDISrZlE_RZ4-8\", 4, 0)", "new EmuController(\"6003087448525-id_4dc09ff0612184c51197177\", \"AQAVDQezDWg8RCTH6EnPLCILHIX4upfP5v0NJ_-npYstbN0e4SWpCrfbYAQRM_9dVfozxS89XSxUt1jgEQpRbTHE3sfkcngkwyKIjKGhmIS8rKfDX_gP4ER0NnVJlJyX6FaGRul0h2UUYxnxj3uaIsq7LzcI36r4lBTXBg1THtRC2pZ1MuUzvkTlYlwh4B-c5lXwt-6nKTTMdoZsTRsUDG_JTAPHeTV0-FYMr-1roaJpR_j--aw_MxJ6NxFEbTvkyL4QVN-ZRpWfeovChdYk4j_cgxoxRE-qm-u_hYcVbbtVrQXq0kVtHHhX8ijyeLt-4kZcM6gfnHpfBkB06z69adcA9rzWLA6VEo4_OFthPtc2SydkBs6DyAx51mAG3mBgnXXBJciYrQzWM-vSvODcV1dKTb5tSxO81Uswl-3Uo9Jf_VzfUgoKdeHyQeem31WMUmYm9kxCOVvKy4p7sE09GQoAfPBoz4MOrAgs3MFBFzpwIvKyZGvE6cX8haiK4POdP1zrEnMLFDyF0HRAaxfl4gKYw9kpGOtkrwezzU_biPYxV26-sUjXvPGx87WAZszqlIosXOJVux33eJD3V5bDcFD06Faze9OE5Segl4Tdmd0VZs73lt4PGXfF90QLCqZeUuNUUCkhRRRsP99SdW99Ghx0JncIQDpfX3fByce58jmKSCFWjcHy5qTPlryVI3KVow-XMLiguVmdbicCBGq-7im00hCmjH2-5HCuQnhHafNHUSZzZiHTg4KaTqvIMTfQIXs\", 4, 0)", "new EmuController(\"6003788660296-id_4dc09ff0612299683640305\", \"AQCvUWOfDiphu5NGe7r6dBna_IEvTbjrshIpxmOlMO3jwk650AHb_T03II0mnzLwpdy617kQMD8n8RIE_YqIE1hNxxoZL4M4ba8QiPz6h-u003c\/h4>\JW8WSPFBt1RSMeJQV7swF6HWeAm3Ew0fphxMwpdYDIu2fbEGLujVFCKwtMCzN6As6berB8z7iOoWdsAFulXLBLvHID0-Dn0_qCxF-AKl0b9s8cWBwF9fG1oI0r1TNQZGILLW8daCOkkjhpCUOHkXI6PFxyw5CXYLSmnVAxpvougwh7vt-NV3RWPuYnLN1QOvf07q2DRv-2wY1JUexmcWl6f5zquDJfEW3CxlluJ76eKZowfiGW-V-1M9K9whgfALkEjGDA-JM9P_lfXaukcmDDwAIHLFwG_7a9jNP4XmbLUyQEhUesxkImM5z7IAzt-HBIbtDfD8kHt50AG3nm3GEHv-yChqKMWqmcuzyYgmMGaXXKCd9Pb2a_pcF-QR_YIg2qgptFnn82D7Bb9Tedmce-FveNix9Ej7_fwr-IAncYwABNrs9zX34TkbLgvqhvH9RayLDXO7GnGWB_I4jorTbmNvpxf0rG8aXp3udXdNTEZAjmU3Yp1TOySAXY2Z5Ju6oYS51-tQ2SZIihYsa49TxQdSHet9vO4tjY_7rwT8Cou_TrmFWwZXuQTGwfUByP9Cl6wrUNhHeW3zbrB-BAxofxqcGQ44C7HPsvVTdkSOKhx60zaWaaBnDZ87QjEAgNJ-NjN8EqO_jMq3ig2Vn2CKzBhhQ\", 4, 0)", "new EmuController(\"6002985380734-id_4dc09ff06123a8641112115\", \"AQBkHx98vGQ8Bn2h8R42L-S1OQfGO1ksTR41Mds3V7wEwzKNgBG4H2o-EHRvRSd9SsIPGChah-NHU5Jt_wbtng06_Dw0U0WkxfBkFx374OINZj69o69sPYmoQZlY2xsClxS0T2t_h7zs9RzX4NpvYtSL6I3MALL0CsWS0KLv-CQHUF-IWpeNj6uGLG4efTFLBBMeQM0-Wr1IWYXU6oQZJRPwS7trOw4xW56wGBnhGPv1KRwr8ITU4NGUZlBKrUNRvx1SeyFn4MYNCrzXG0W_HxsWWv_ekTeDefvMF0gHZNDgcA07-FLEYxfCEzBL498OERPhoyBsmFE9fGbOY1EcO_LB_moqIncJF-TosooObw7f4BMZwHMxfGgju_UKndyeRq_l3pcTkSyjhbZY5-1sjojM8AI9VxCLdQms5QA7lvflmdPpwXS3b8UmCNfEtIy4iGED7yL7p1CKAKgJcO4jzmJ3Epk9tK38zy3Nv5yGB0-63dwjcvZMoTJMa545d2Vgs7J5_OiD6gA5fX4oB84m1dcI5e2G6AgzXAsWTUSuIGliPQr2oFjaz2mOzepyCvoatPjr1rtDkX_xNK9S27jXSuu9k0tiKCOkPsdccPO6235zCT0HeiPI0sHsUTpDmiFXHyFx0r_Kus5iCU5CjKjX1okSuKQL7WM5HTBvYRCAbPNthqa9oNDDNmwNG-Im7wNZHEw4ZZuXpqg4UolyUZAkY7dKBRvGmK0sSGSIjIISOq1e6zBdekf7OlZ5yLnCwhAI_5E\", 4, 0)"],
        "onafterload": ["new EmuTracker(\"6002939839588-id_4dc09ff0611f60c83869379\", false)", "new EmuTracker(\"6003087448525-id_4dc09ff0612184c51197177\", false)", "new EmuTracker(\"6003788660296-id_4dc09ff0612299683640305\", false)", "new EmuTracker(\"6002985380734-id_4dc09ff06123a8641112115\", false)"],
        "refresh_pagelets": ["c4dc09ff06275f0732488206"],
        "content": {
            "pagelet_ego_pane": "\u003cdiv id=\"c4dc09ff06275f0732488206\">\u003cdiv class=\"ego_column egoOrganicColumn\">\u003cdiv class=\"ego_section\">\u003cdiv class=\"uiHeader uiHeaderTopAndBottomBorder mbs uiSideHeader\">\u003cdiv class=\"clearfix uiHeaderTop\">\u003ca class=\"uiHeaderActions rfloat\" href=\"\/l.php?u=\u00252Ffind-friends\u00252Fbrowser\u00252F\u00253Fref\u00253Dpsa&amp;h=1ef37&amp;cb=3&amp;p=AQCicK3gLdJTaaW2xZUw3DWp7N89P5QwZvSEfn3y2vOqjXyzr60nDcHEPY7Y9x7LpK9-J5evLB7_Dwm9F4d0k5i9sQ-CXiH_GXc-toIfka4dUSK_\">See All\u003c\/a>\u003cdiv>\u003ch4 class=\"uiHeaderTitle\">People You May Know\u003c\/div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That GM script is not removing the `script` node, it is just "hiding" it -- which would never have an effect.

It is possible for GM to actually remove that `script` node but, alas, this will not happen before the node has run.  Deleting it after that will not stop the operation, as the JS is already loaded into memory.

The *easiest* thing to do is to delete the container that is displaying the PYMK cruft.
I don't use Facebook, but from your code it appears that the container might have the id, "pagelet_ego_pane".  In which case, you could delete it like:

```
var PYMK_Container  = document.getElementById ('pagelet_ego_pane');
if (PYMK_Container) PYMK_Container.parentNode.removeChild (PYMK_Container);
```

You could also try to delete the annoying function, which may or may not be possible.  The function *appears* to be set with that `new UIPagelet(\"c4dc09ff06275f0732488206\"` code.  So, if you can find the corresponding function, you can try deleting it with:

```
unsafeWindow.OffendingFunctionName = function() { return; }
```

If that works, it may cut down on the JavaScript "churn" that might slow down that page.

As for stopping your name from showing up in other people's PYMK, that is something that is done by the Facebook servers, there may be a user setting that they have, otherwise you'll have to send Facebook a "sternly worded letter". ;)

Comment: This looks like the answer, although I'll have to wait for when PYMK shows up randomly again.  As far as that second solution, didn't know what you meant "find the corresponding function". This is the only occurence in the html file of the string "UIPagelet", so presumably I would have to search in the downloaded .js files.

Comment: Better to use a tool like [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) to find the function.  But, don't sweat it; killing the function was gravy, anyway.

Comment: Well, I am concerned about the overhead of doing a string search of every single script element, so I will give that second solution a shot as well I think - will it all be clear when I find where UIPagelet is defined?

Comment: (I edited the original post to include the entire script element up to PYMK)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Why would there be "overhead of doing a string search of every single script element"?  Your script does not need to do this, nor does Facebook.    As for finding the definition of `UIPagelet()`, sure that will help.  But, diving through bloated, commercial JS is not for the squeamish.

Comment: Nevermind - I was thinking that  with the first solution you provided I would still be iterating through every script node on the page as I am currently (and there are a lot of them).  I understood your code, just escaped me that I was no longer searching through all the script nodes.  Don't really know much JS so really didn't comprehend the second solution, but no matter .  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to do it would be to just add a user style sheet that hides the offending nodes, no javascript necessary.

However if you want a simple method that just works "out of the box" for hiding the "People You May Know" box, the [FB Purity](http://www.fbpurity.com) browser addon (also available as a greasemonkey script )  has an option for hiding the PYMK box, along with options for hiding most other boxes / links on the site.